# Using PHP to Dynamically create multiple unique buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to dynamically create multiple buttons which eventually will have unique click events.  The "title or name" of each button is stored in a DB.  I have verified, independently, the code to create a dynamic button works and I have also verified my query works properly as well as my "while" loop.  Following is my code:

```
$q="SELECT sess_desc, sess_butt, sess_tag FROM Sessions ORDER BY DateEstab";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
if ($r) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $image = imagecreate(248,53);
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 255); //text box background color
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,255); //Font color
    if(!isset($_GET['size'])) $_GET['size'] = 18;  //text size
    if(!isset($_GET['text'])) $_GET['text'] = $row['sess_butt']; //button lable
imagettftext($image, $_GET['size'], 0, 20,35, $white, "tahoma",$_GET['text']);

echo '<tr><td align="left">' . imagepng($image) . imagedestroy($image) .'</td>
      <td align="left">' . $row['sess_desc'] . '</td>
      '</td><td align="left">' . $row['sess_tag'] . '</td> </tr>';
}
}
```

Here is the beginning of the results when I run the script (it continues).
   �PNG  IHDR�5��;RPLTE�����������__�����??��`!5IDATX��ԻO�P ��TڎJ��Fѹ&>ƶ�:����>��#q�����

I was expecting blue rectangular buttons with a white label.  What do I need to do to make this work using php or do I need to look for a solution using JS (I do not know JS very well)?  I have looked at "similar question", the php manual and other articles I found searching the internet.

Is this even possible?  I ran the script for creating a button and it works fine if I define $_GET['text']= "Hello Everyone", but I am trying to pull the "text" from a DB table.  Again, I want to create multiple buttons from multiple entries in the DB. Specifically, the sess_butt column.  I even limited my query to "1" and that did not work either...same results.

Comment: You should check the manual for: `imagepng()`. It does NOT output a HTML-image tag. It outputs the actual image content. [imagepng()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to embed images into your HTML, you need to have them base64 encoded. Something like:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,base_64_encode(imagepng($image))"/>
```

I also recommend you not to do this and generate url's instead which will be hitting your other script which will be just doing the image generation.

Comment: I think you missed some PHP-tags...  and it's just `base64_encode()`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It is not supposed to be exact php code, just a rough direction to move into

Comment: Sorry, that did not help.  I modified my question in hopes of being a little more clear on what I want and what I tried.

Comment: What do you see in html when you try that?

Comment: I get the alt message "Embedded Image"

Comment: @Learner post your html code for the generated page please. Probably you'll have to upload it to external service like github and post a link here